# missing pixels css fixed div wrapper

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to get divs to fit perfectly in a wrapper using fixed pixels for width and height. Although I'm confused as to how the pixels don't add up properly.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="div1">
        <img src="image.png" alt="image" class="image">
    </div>

    <div class="div2">

    </div>

    <div class="div3">

    </div>

    <div class="div4">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    height: 455px;
    width: 690px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

 .image {
    max-width: 172px;
    max-height: 172px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}

.div2 {
    height: 172px;
    width: 277px;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color: purple;
}

.div3 {
    width: 159px;
    height: 188px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-left: 4px solid blue;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: purple;
}

.div4 {
    background: url(image.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 690px;
    height: 265px;
}
```

If the parent div is 690px wide why can't the child divs add up to 690 with calculated widths, margin and boarders.

(div1)180 + 30 + (div2)285 + 30 + (div3)165 = 690px

If you look at div 3 it's right border can't be seen. You have to reduce the width by 7px to see it.

This is also happening vertically with a 190px div3 height meant to touch div4 exactly but is off by 4px.

Is this a browser issue? Default Alignment issues I'm not aware of? I'm really curious to know why this happens!

Any feedback would be appreciated. : )

Comment: It has to do with the `display:inline-block`s. See: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put comments like this in your HTML you can fix the top but for the image in the 2nd line I dont know yet I continue trying

OK SO I did put the 1st line in a div "test" and gaved him display:block and overflow hidden to take away the the space under and then I did give the div1 fixed heigth and width 180px (image+border)

```css
#wrapper {
    height: 455px;
    width: 690px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
 
}

.test{
    display:block;
     overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 {
  height:180px;
  width:180px;

    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
        
}

 .image {
    max-width: 172px;
    max-height: 172px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    border: 4px solid blue;
}

.div2 {
    height: 172px;
    width: 277px;
    border: 4px solid blue;
   display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color: purple;
}

.div3 {
    width: 159px;
    height: 188px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-left: 4px solid blue;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: purple;
}

.div4 {
   background: url('http://lorempixel.com/690/265/cats') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 690px;
    height: 265px;
     display:block;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="test">
  
 
  <div class="div1">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/172/172/cats" alt="image" class="image">

    </div><!--

    --><div class="div2">

    </div><!--

    --><div class="div3">

    </div><!--

    --> </div><div class="div4">

        </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: @Jonathan002 I hope you understand my bad english ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was so confused at first when you suggested comments as a fix but then learned about html white space.. Awesome man! : )

Answer (score -1):

have you checked out box-sizing feature?
Here is some links that might be helpful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: The OP *is* accounting for the border-widths in his math.

Comment: border-box fixing this issue if you set box-sizing:border-box;
https://plnkr.co/edit/FE046eIF68EF7Qv7Yqw6?p=preview